# Unable to update column value of datatype byte[] in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

My user-authentication table "AuthUser" looks like :

```
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  username character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  password bytea[],
  salt bytea[]
```

POJO representation  :

```
  ...
  private byte[]            password;

  private byte[]            salt;
  ... 
  getter setter methods
```

I used following query for updating the salt and encrypted password as :

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public void updateSaltAndPasswordByUsername(String username, byte[] salt, byte[] password) {
    String hql = "UPDATE AuthUser SET password= ? , salt= ? WHERE username = ? ";
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setBinary(0, password).setBinary(1, salt).setString(2, username).executeUpdate();
  }
```

But it gives error  as :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "password" is of type bytea[] but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I want to save salt and password in byte[] in database.

Am I missed any thing?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  username character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  password bytea,
  salt bytea
```

Note that `bytea[]` is equal to `bytea ARRAY` that will expect data of type `{byte[], byte[],...}`